# Is it possible to have a Linux VFS cache with a FUSE filesystem?

Tags: c, linux, redis, fuse, vfs

It seems that the Linux VFS cache does not work by default with a FUSE filesystem. For example, the "read" call seems to be systematically forwarded to the FUSE filesystem.

I work on a FUSE specific remote filesystem. I need a very aggressive cache.

Do I need to implement my own page cache? Or is it possible to activate the Linux VFS cache for this particular FUSE filesystem? Or does someone know a good proxy/cache FUSE filesystem (or a kind of C library to do that without reinventing the wheel)?

Bonus question:

If I have to implement my own page cache, I think to use a REDIS daemon to do the LRU stuff. I'm nearly sure that it can be a good option for caching metadata. But for pages, I'm not sure that it will be better than a simple local directory (with VFS cache) or than /dev/shm. But I will lose LRU automatic cleaning. Does someone know a sort of /dev/shm with automatic LRU cleaning?

Some additional information: the filesystem is read-only and the remote side is nearly immutable; the remote side contains very big files that I can't copy to a local directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think VFS cache will not work on FUSE. There are caching solutions for FUSE or you can implement yours.

With a small search, I found [fuse-cache](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-cache/); they claim that it is simple.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But fuse-cache is not good for me because I have very big files on the remote side that I can't simply copy to a local directory. I need a cache at the page level because the cient side open only specific parts of these big files.

Comment: Then it seems it is hard to find a generic solution. Try to implement yours.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the FUSE `auto_cache` option.  FUSE will cache the data and only make several metadata calls to check if the file size or modification timestamp has changed.

Comment: `kernel_cache` is also an option now, with a warning about consistency