# The VFS cache over fuse filesystem (glusterfs mounted by fuse)

Tags: linux, caching, fuse, vfs, glusterfs

VFS cache didn't work on FUSE?In the GlusterFS client,I mounted the GlusterFS volume to local /mnt/glusterfs by fuse.But when I excuted "time ls /mnt/glusterfs",the dentry was cached in remote nodes rather than the MOUNT node.And I read a file which located in remote nodes,it was cached in the MOUNT node.How to explain the phenomenon??

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4558729/196561

Comment: thank you, i have noticed the question you mentioned just now.Is there some options in VFS or FUSE or Linux kernel to solve the problem?

Comment: There may be some info from glusterfs side: http://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/Features/caching "Current status Proposed" - it is not implemented (at jan 2015). You may also try to find some info about fuse-cache https://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-cache/ ...

Comment: Thank you so much.